# htaccess Rewrite Rule For Multiple Site Sections

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to roll my own user registration script in PHP. I have users and groups.

I want people to be able to access user profiles at domain.com/users/username

and group profiles at domain.com/groups/groupname

In my htaccess I have the following:

```
Options -Indexes 

<Files "config.php">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</Files>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users/index.php?username=$1
```

This works for users but I have no idea how to modify this to work for groups too. I'm sure this is a very simple adjustment but I've had little luck Googling solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your 2 rules setup like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/?$ /users/index.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^groups/([^/]+)/?$ /groups/index.php?groupname=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Because `RewriteCond` are only applicable to very next `RewriteRule`